# ReactNative: How to have 2nd Text components share the line of 1 Text component spill over

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In React Native is it possible for 2nd  component to use the space that was partially used by 1st Text component spill over?

Example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export const TextProto = () => {

    return <View>

        <Text style={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'green'}}>{'str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1 str-1'}</Text>
        <Text style={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'green'}}>{'str-2 str-2'}</Text>
    </View>
};
```

Renders as:

[image]

Is it possible to render this as (preferably through styling settings):

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use just one < Text > and '\n' to change to the next line?

Comment: You could change outer view with a text component, that way you can gain what you want. But border will not work for text components that are inside of a text component. (as you can see here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10775) But you can use this bad workaround https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10775#issuecomment-373880186

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga i guess op wants it to be responsive and a feel like css display inline

Answer (score 1):

As **@Uğur Eren** [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710914/reactnative-how-to-have-2nd-text-components-share-the-line-of-1-text-component#comment112662766_63710914), borders will not work for text components but you can achieve similar effect by using different background color for each word in your string or set of strings.

Below is a simple implementation for your case:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";


const sentences = [
  {
    backgroundColor: "#cfa",
    color: "#000",
    sentence: "This is my first line that is very very long"
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#edf",
    color: "#000",
    sentence: "There it is a second one"
  },
  { backgroundColor: "#ecd", color: "#000", sentence: "Lorem ipsum veliyedin" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {sentences.map(({ color, backgroundColor, sentence }) => {
        return sentence.split(" ").map((word) => {
          return (
            <Text style={[styles.text, { color, backgroundColor }]}>
              {word}
            </Text>
          );
        });
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignSelf: "flex-start"
  },
  sentence: {
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignSelf: "flex-start"
  },
  text: {
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#eee"
    // margin:5
  }
});
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-feynman-9od2y)